# Is MongoDB conditional aggregation available in Meteor 1.4.x ?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to publish certain fields to a page based on a parameter of a document in a mongo collection.  This is from the MongoDB manual: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Does Meteor support conditional aggregation?

```
    return Cases.find({
            subscribers: { $in: [this.userId] }
            }, {
            fields: { $cond: [ { $eq: ['classified', true] } , Cases.privateFields, Cases.publicFields ] }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I realized I was approaching aggregates incorrectly.  After doing some research on options to implement aggregation (meteorhacks) I decided to implement my own, which keeps the reactivity of the collection:

Extend Mongo.Collection

```
class CasesCollection extends Mongo.Collection {
    conditionalFields(selector, modifier) {
        let cond = modifier.fields[0],
            pos = modifier.fields[1],
            neg = modifier.fields[2];

        if ( cond ) {
            modifier = { fields: pos };
        } else {
            modifier = { fields: neg };
        }

        const cursor = this.find(selector, modifier);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Meteor.publish('cases.dashboard', function casesDashboard() {
    if (!this.userId) {
        return this.ready();
    }
    return Cases.conditionalFields({
            subscribers: { $in: [this.userId] }
        }, {
            fields: [ { $eq: ['classified', true] } , Cases.privateDashboardFields, Cases.dashboardFields ]
        });
});
```